# How to draw an isosurface in the same figure with a scatter3 plot in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a 3D volume and a 3D point cloud. How can I draw the point cloud, along with an `isosurface` of the volume, without overwriting the scatter plot? Using `patch` to draw the isosurface always wipes away the `scatter3` plot.

Comment: Just to check - are you using `hold on`?

Comment: unfortunately, `hold on` doesn't do the trick

Comment: OK - it was worth checking. Can you post some example code that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things to try.

1. Draw the surface use patches first.  (`h = patch(...)`, then set `hold on`)
2. Make the patches semi-transparent.  This will let you see if the scatter items are still there, just hidden.  It also tells the renderer that everything needs to be plotted, which can prevent some sorts of graphics bugs.

   `set(h,'faceAlpha',0.5)`
3. Try using `plot3` instead of `scatter3`.  This does not allow you to change individual marker sizes or colors, but it is much easier on Matlab.   Even if you need the `scatter3` features, this is worth trying as a debugging step.