# MATLAB gui and figure and axes

Tags: matlab, user-interface, visualization, figure

I have an iso-surface and a scatter3 objects. I want to merge them into the axes object of the GUI. How do I do that? It looks like I can keep only one children in an axes object.

I also settled for opening a new figure from the GUI which contains the two objects, but it seems that the figure inherits the properties of the GUI!

```
base = patch(isosurface(atlas,0));
isonormals(atlas,base);
...
hold on;
...
scatter3(L(:,2)', L(:,1)', L(:,3)', L(:,4)', L(:,5)', '.');
```

And the result is just the scatter3 plot.
Same thing if I write

```
points = scatter3(L(:,2)', L(:,1)', L(:,3)', L(:,4)', L(:,5)', '.');
set( handles.axes, 'Children', [base, points]);
```

**UPDATE**
I tried to write an independent function (outside the GUI function) to generate the figure I want. If I call that procedure from the GUI it doesn't work, but if I call that procedure from the MATLAB console, it works.

PS the waitbar looks like this

[image: waitbar]

Is this normal?

Comment: What properties of the GUI?

Comment: An `axe` object can definitely contain multiple children. Although as Airuno2L  answered, I would make sure that the `hold` property doesn't delete the old children when you add new ones.

Comment: It looks like someone else had a similar problem before! Take a look at this it might help you: [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8167416/how-to-draw-an-isosurface-in-the-same-figure-with-a-scatter3-plot-in-matlab)  or [that link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18646879/matlab-using-scatter3-and-mesh-at-the-same-time). If you're still stuck please let us know.

Comment: nope, that's not working. I posted the code in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok solved. It was the waitbar which interfered with the GUI.

Apparently, hold on was plotting the isosurface on the waitbar.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but try plotting one, then use the "[hold on](http://nf.nci.org.au/facilities/software/Matlab/techdoc/ref/hold.html)" command, then plot the other. That should plot the second one without erasing the first. Is that what you're asking to do?

Comment: nope, hold on doesn't work.
I post the code in the question, take a look.